# In Google Cloud Platform, is it require for each IOT Core device to have separate pub/sub topic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iot

I am publishing ESP data to Google Cloud IOT via MQTT to a particular topic. But If I have many devices data, then is it necessary to **create different topic for each device**? If Yes, then how can I trigger a **single cloud function for multiple topics**.
I couldn't find it anywhere on the Google Cloud Platform Documentation. So please help me!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the message contain the [attributes of your device](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events). Like this, you can know the context of the message and process all the messages by the same Cloud Functions.